# c# Adding new properties to all Windows in my App

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I'm trying to add a few extra base properties (somewhere) in my project so that every window I create will automatically inherit these properties.

E.g. each window will have a "block_count" based on the area of the window

For context, I'm using a WPF project.

**Currently trying:** I've created an `abstract` window class with my desired properties and then defined my `MainWindow` as one of these types to inherit the property and method...

But when coding in my MainWindow class I still can't access the property or method even though it should have inherited them? Where am I going wrong or what is the best way to add properties to all windows in my project?

---

**My Abstract Window class**

```
public abstract partial class AbWinDefiner : Window
{

    private int _block_count;

    private void get_block_count()
    {
        _block_count = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Width * Height / 32));
    }

    public AbWinDefiner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

---

**My Main Window class**

```
public partial class MainWindow : AbWinDefiner
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it protected, not private

Comment: Make what protected instead of private? I changed both _block_count and the method to protected but still can't access it in the child class